# In solidity, what's the need of verifying 'address(this)' is a contract?

Tags: solidity, initializer, openzeppelin

In openzeppelin's `Initializable.sol` library(v4.7.0), there is a `modifier initializer()` that checks if a function has already been initialized. In the require statement, it checks the value of `_initialized` which I understand. But in addition, it also verifies whether `address(this)` is a contract or not through `AddressUpgradeable.isContract(address(this)`. Why is this needed? See code and questions below.

```
    modifier initializer() {
    bool isTopLevelCall = !_initializing;
    require(
        (isTopLevelCall && _initialized < 1) || (!AddressUpgradeable.isContract(address(this)) && _initialized == 1),
        "Initializable: contract is already initialized"
    );
    _initialized = 1;
    if (isTopLevelCall) {
        _initializing = true;
    }
    _;
    if (isTopLevelCall) {
        _initializing = false;
        emit Initialized(1);
    }
}
```

1. In what condition, `address(this)` would ever not be a contract? Wouldn't `address(this)` always refer to the instance of the smart contract?
2. In what condition `(!AddressUpgradeable.isContract(address(this)) && _initialized == 1)` will return true? Because if `_initialized==1`, it means the function has been initialized. Then why would we still allow this extra condition to pass?
   Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *1. In what condition, `address(this)` would ever not be a contract?*

The OpenZeppelin `isContract()` function checks if `code` property of the address is non-empty ([GitHub](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.8.1/contracts/utils/Address.sol#L36)).

The `code` is still empty while executing a constructor. For example the below code emits `NotContract` even though it's effectively executed from a contract address.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract Caller {
    event IsContract();
    event NotContract();

    constructor(Target target) {
        if (target.isCallerContract()) {
            emit IsContract();
        } else {
            emit NotContract();
        }
    }
}

contract Target {
    function isCallerContract() external view returns (bool) {
        return msg.sender.code.length != 0;
    }
}
```

> *In what condition `(!AddressUpgradeable.isContract(address(this)) && _initialized == 1)` will return true?*

Constructor calling 2 functions that both have the `initializer` modifier. Or the same function two times (from within the constructor).

During the second function call, `_initialized` is already `1`.